# Firebase Phone Auth OTP Message template issue

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, one-time-password

I know that **we can't change** the email verification template or the SMS verification template.

I have already set **Public-Facing Name** which is working till the date. But today I got OTP with another text instead of that name.

> 123345 is your verification code. egad5adfe/g

What is that last word **egad5adfe/g** and why it is coming instead of Public-Facing Name?

I haven't change anything in the last couple of days. Why it happened don't know. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Im not so sure of this but I think you have to publish the app on the Play Store to see the name in the SMS. If your app published yet or just in the development phase?

Comment: It will show your puplic facing name once Production (As uploading the App to Google Play Store or App Store) Or uploading the App to live Domain (For Websites) That is All :)

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify that you're facing this issue on production ?
Once you deploy your application it'll reflect the actual name.

Comment: I have tried but not working in production too. I downloaded the app from the play store and tried.